# How to diagnose DNS problems after switching to Route 53

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-name, dns-hosting, amazon-route53

My domain was purchased with Enom and up until a few days ago I was using their DNS. I made the switch to Amazon Route 53 and set up all my records there. Every time I've tweaked the records I've updated the SOA serial. No IP's changed, so I expected little to no real problems, the records were duplicated and name servers changed, that's all.

I've tested my site from a wide range of locations and have no idea what's going on:

- My site works fine from my ISP
- It doesn't from my phone's ISP, who would not have had a cached record, however subdomains work fine
- Pingdom reports my site is up or down, depending on what location it is. It's either "DNS error", "Unknown target" or working but with quite a high response time (1-2 seconds).
- Pingdoms online traceroute tool returns an "Invalid host" error while their full page test tool works fine
- Most online DNS tools show Amazon's servers are responding fine with my domain and the right IP address. Using page testing tools, some can connect to my site but others can't.

Is there any definitive way to check if my configuration is correct? I don't know how to interpret all this mixed information. I know DNS changes can cause headaches but as no IP information has changed, I thought it wouldn't be a big deal if a cached record is used.

Thanks if you can help.

Comment: Can you provide the real domain? Maybe a little bit of digging will help.

Answer (score 1):

Shooting in the dark, the behavior that you are seeing might point toward a wrong list of DNS servers being registered for the domain. You can try the [Zonecheck tool](http://www.zonecheck.fr/demo/) that will identify the most common problems.

Comment: Thanks very much, gave that a go and I got a success result with only a warning about the NS being part of the same Autonomous System, so no big deal I think. I hate problems that are difficult to diagnose, especially with limited knowledge but thanks.

Comment: Was that the only change you made was to change the NS's? The zone transferred exactly as it was?